# How to get the instance of an object as a string?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the instance of an object returned as a string representation e.g. '0x12345678' or just '12345678' ?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
string myObjectsInstanceAsAString = myObject.instance.ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: override ToString() to retrieve what you want. What about that?

Comment: What type is "instance"?

Comment: What is that number supposed to mean? If it is some kind of unique ID (i.e. memory location): That's not possible in C#. The memory location of an object can change over time as the GC performs its work.

Comment: `myObject` is already the instance ;)

Comment: The 'number' is just some unique text, generated somehow from the instance, that I can use for a sort elsewhere.

Comment: This isn't even pseudocode mate, this works in C#!

Comment: @antonijn: I don't think 'instance' is a valid keyword in C#.

Comment: If you're using this for sorting purposes, you probably don't want this inside of `ToString()` - instead you probably want to implement `IComparable` and/or the generic version. This will let you compare objects based on your calculation, manually, or using the default sort of something like a `List<T>`.

Comment: @Surfbutler In that case I do not understand what you mean by instance. What exactly do you mean by "instance of an object"? I think you might have your definitions confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
    private static int _counter = 0;
    private int _id;
    public MyClass() {
        _id = ++_counter;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return _id.ToString();
    }
}
```

I don't know that that would be a useful value to sort on, but it seems to do what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, just tried it, and that works - exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to `override` the `ToString()` `method` for the `object` `type`.

```
public override string ToString(){

   // do implementation here
}
```

[MSDN: How to: Override the ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that if you don't override it, it will return the type name.

Comment: Yes, but what would I override it with? I need to return a unique number (as a string) based on the instance.

Comment: @Surfbutler - So generate a unique number and convert it to a String.  Be sure what you generate is actually unique most people fail when they attempt to generate unique numbers.

Comment: Generate a random number set it to a property and then return it as a string then.

Comment: You could put a static counter member in the class, and store the current value to a private member variable inside the constructor.  Then in ToString, return the stored value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a string number based on the instance you may try this:

```
yourInstance.GetHashCode().ToString();
```

Also you can improve the return value by overriding the `GetHashCode` method, so you can be sure it will returns a unique number.

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily unique. The hash code for an integer is just defined as the integer itself, for instance.

Comment: @antonijn: Yes, agreed. According to MSDN, GetHashCode shouldn't be used for this purpose. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, if you're using this for sorting purposes, implement `IComparable` instead:

```
public class Foo : IComparable<Foo> {
    public int CompareTo(Foo other) {
        return SomeCalculation.CompareTo(other.SomeCalculation());
    }

    private int SomeCalculation() {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

This will allow you to sort your objects using the default sorter, or manually compare one to another.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I already have a IComparer<myclassname>.Compare function. It's that where I needed to get the unique representation of an instance. Once I added the solution proposed by djs, everything works fine. Thanks, +1 for suggesting Compare anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by string representation. An object can be represented as a string in a number of ways. The default way of doing it in .NET is returning the typename. I.e. if you write this code:

```
class MyClass { }

// In the main function
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(mc.ToString());
```

Will output `MyClass`.

However, this is usually not what you want. You usually have a custom way your class should be represented. I.e. in a a `DateTime` class/struct your `ToString` method should return a string containing the date and time.

To make a custom string representation for a **type**, you need to override the `ToString` method from `System.Object`:

```
class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string fName, string lName) {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
    }

    public override void ToString() {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}

// in your main method
Person p = new Person("Albert", "Einstein");
Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
```

This will output `Albert Einstein`.

Comment: Yes thanks Antonijn - I already have fields and code like this in my class, but they are all the same across different instances, so I needed some way of generating a unique id for each instance. The other guy's solution fitted the bill. +1 though for a useful answer in slightly different circumstances. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to assign a unique ID for each instance of your class you could create a private static variable for your class and increment and assign this value to an instance property during the constructor

```
public class MyClass {

    private static long INSTANCE_ID = 0;
    private long ID;

    //ctor
    public MyClass() {
         this.ID = INSTANCE_ID++;
    }

    //You could build your string method based on the ID if you wanted to...
    public long getID() {
         return ID;
    }

}
```

**EDIT** I didn't see @djs comment before posting this answer. This is the exact same idea as his.